# Abort this node-fetch request without aborting all other requests

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

The only way I found to set a timeout on a `node-fetch` request is to use the `abort-controller`:

```js
import AbortController from 'abort-controller'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const fetchWithTimeout = async (url, options) => {
  const controller = new AbortController()
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    controller.abort()
  }, 10000)
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    signal: controller.signal,
    ...options
  })
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  return response.text()
}
```

Besides the fact that this looks ugly, it also has a huge issue that I don't know how to dodge:
The `controller.abort()` aborts ALL current requests, not just one. So, if I call `fetchWithTimeout()` 10 times in parallel and one of them gets aborted, then all the others get aborted too.

I've kinda solved it with even more awkward code:

```js
import AbortController from 'abort-controller'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const aborted = {}
const fetchWithTimeout = async (url, options) => {
  const controller = new AbortController()
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    aborted[url] = true
    controller.abort()
  }, 10000)
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      signal: controller.signal,
      ...options
    })
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    return response.text()
  } catch (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    if (aborted[url] || e?.type !== 'aborted') {
      delete aborted[url]
      throw e
    } else {
      return await fetchWithTimeout(url, options)
    }
  }
}
```

But this is so wrong and inefficient. What else can I do with it besides replacing node-fetch with an alternative?

Comment: I don't think your first example looks all that ugly. As for it aborting _all_ requests I don't believe that should be happening unless there's a bug in node-fetch. Could you show the part of the code that calls `fetchWithTimeout`? The problem might just be in how you're handling the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the behaviour of `controller.abort()` aborting ALL current requests, but it seems to work as expected and I doubt that it's a bug in `node-fetch`.

I think the problem is how you handle the errors when you execute the requests in parallel (presumably) using `Promise.all`. As stated [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) it rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error.

You are probably looking for [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead, as it resolves after **all** of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected independently of each other. So it could look something like this:

```
(async () => {
    const parallelRequests = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        parallelRequests.push(fetchWithTimeout('http://some-url.com'));
    }
    const result = await Promise.allSettled(parallelRequests);
    // result will be an array holding status information about each promise and the resolved value or the rejected error
})();
```

The reason why your second approach works with `Promise.all`, is that you actually catch and handle errors from the fetch-call. But be aware that in case of non-aborted error, you re-throw the error which will again cause an immediate rejection regardless of the other requests.

Comment: This is probably the correct solution. If 10 different requests are created using the same function but each with their own Abort Controller, then one rejection shouldn't "abort" the remaining 9 requests. Unless, as @eol has stated, you're using `Promise.all()` @stkvtflw

Answer (score 0):

I've spent too many hours on various node fetch libraries. Just use curl. It just works.

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process'

async function curl (url: string) {
  return await new Promise(async resolve => {
    const command = `curl "${url}" -L --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 12`
    exec(command, { maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 * 10 }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err, stderr)
        resolve('')
      } else {
        resolve(stdout)
      }
    })
  })
}

export default curl
```

Comment: I'm confused... What exactly did you want? This solution has little type-safety (unless you implement it, which is significantly more work). Wouldn't you want to continue using a library which offers all these abstraction for you?

Comment: All I want is to retrieve the url content apparently. I don't care what library will do that.
The thing is, aborting requests issue is just one among many with node fetch libraries. Poor proxy handling, poor redirects following, inability to handle simplest http -> https redirects... errors, errors, errors. The curl does everything simply and out of the box without all these headaches.

Comment: @stkvtflw: Out of curiousity I'd still appreciate some feedback on my answer :)

Comment: @stkvtflw [node-libcurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl) might be it for you then :) Unless you're okay with making your own interface, I'd recommend using a pre-existing solution (especially if you're planning on growing the project)

Comment: Thats a really bad solution. you do understand that curl('; init 0;'); in that case, would turn off your server? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need use `await response.text()`
2. `clearTimeout(timeout)` after `await response.text()`, not before.